# How to fix "Radio" for multiple-steps in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make some form validation. If you click the radio button, you can go to the next step, but if you don't click it, you can't proceed. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap Multi Step Registration Form Template</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/css/form-elements.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/css/style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicon and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/ico/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">

</head>

<body background="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/img/backgrounds/green.jpg">
<?php //$this->load->view($view) ?>

<!-- Top content -->
<div class="top-content">

    <div class="inner-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text">
                    <h1><strong>KUISIONER RAWAT JALAN</strong></h1>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>
                            <b>RUMAH SAKIT UMUM DAERAH TEBET</b>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">

                    <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="registration-form">

                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-top">
                                <div class="form-top-left">
                                    <h3>Langkah 1 / 3</h3>
                                    <p>Keterangan Responden</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-top-right">
                                    <img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/img/logorsudtebet.png">
                                    <!--<i class="fa fa-user"></i>-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-bottom">

                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label class="col-sm-6">Usia Responden</label>
                                    <input class="form-control col-md-6" type="text" placeholder="Isi Usia Anda" name="usia">
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                                    <label class="col-md-6">Status Perkawinan</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <input class="radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Belum Kawin &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Kawin &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Cerai Hidup &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Cerai Mati &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-top">
                                <div class="form-top-left">
                                    <h3>Step 2 / 3</h3>
                                    <p>Set up your account:</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-top-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-email" placeholder="Email..." class="form-email form-control" id="form-email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-repeat-password">Repeat password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="form-repeat-password" placeholder="Repeat password..."
                                           class="form-repeat-password form-control" id="form-repeat-password">
                                </div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-top">
                                <div class="form-top-left">
                                    <h3>Step 3 / 3</h3>
                                    <p>Social media profiles:</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-top-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-bottom">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-facebook">Facebook</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-facebook" placeholder="Facebook..." class="form-facebook form-control" id="form-facebook">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-twitter">Twitter</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-twitter" placeholder="Twitter..." class="form-twitter form-control" id="form-twitter">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-google-plus">Google plus</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="form-google-plus" placeholder="Google plus..." class="form-google-plus form-control" id="form-google-plus">
                                </div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign me up!</button>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/js/retina-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?=base_url()?>assets/multiplesteps/js/scripts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$('.registration-form fieldset:first-child').fadeIn('slow');

$('.registration-form input[type="text"], .registration-form input[type="password"], .registration-form textarea').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('input-error');
});
```

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: where is radio button onClick event?

Comment: i'm sorry, could you please write the code for radio button onClick ?

`// next step
$('.registration-form .btn-next').on('click', function() {
var parent_fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');
var next_step = true;
parent_fieldset.find('input[type="text"], input[type="radio"],input[type="password"], textarea').each(function() {
if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
$(this).addClass('input-error');
next_step = false;
}
else {
$(this).removeClass('input-error');
}
});
if( next_step ) {
parent_fieldset.fadeOut(400, function() {
$(this).next().fadeIn();
});
}
});`

it's not working